# Laravel 5.7 API return 302

Tags: laravel, rest, api

I am creating REST API using Laravel 5.7, Its alwasys return 302 with Redirection Respose with HTML code as below

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html>
<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://localhost/Ozone/en" />

    <title>Redirecting to http://localhost/Ozone/en</title>
</head>
<body>
    Redirecting to <a href="http://localhost/Ozone/en">http://localhost/Ozone/en</a>.
</body>
```

```
{
    "status": false,
    "message": "Input are not valid",
    "error":
        {
            "contact_number": ["The contact number has already been taken."]
        }
}
```

I want only JSON Response like

```
{
    "status": false,
    "message": "Input are not valid",
    "error": {
        "contact_number": ["The contact number has already been taken."]
    }
}
```

Please Help me

Comment: Does your request have `Accept:application/json` request header value?

Comment: Yes
accept: application/json

Comment: If the framework return a redirection it's because you're using FormRequest and rules ? Am I right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you `want` json response, you need to include `Accept:application/json` in the request header.

Comment: If your issue still persist, please update your question with the request headers.

Comment: It was working fine Previously, suddent it will send 302 Found , I dont Know Why

Comment: Ca update the question with the script you are using to make api calls ?

Comment: every thing is working fine, except return response extra with HTML Response

Comment: Without seeing what's in your script, can't sort out your issue. Please update the question with relevant codes. You only posted the error message though.

Comment: web.php Route Fixed